# Is it possible to launch app script with triggers from Google Sheet API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My case:
I created template google sheet with prepared formulas and connected app script with triggers.
With Python and Google Sheet API I made copy of it and move to some directory.

When I make a copy of file via API, service google account become owner of that. And then when user opens the file and tries to launch app script scenario he gets error : "This script cannot be run because it is owned by the service account. Before running, copy or transfer the project to a valid account." The solution is clear - to copy file manually and launch script. But I want all process to be automated. Is it possible to launch app script with triggers from Google Sheet API or at least ignore somehow that error?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between the owner of the original Spreadsheet, the users except for the owner, the service account, and your python script, and your Google Apps Script. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: It doesn't matter here who is user/owner. Basically I have template file, with edit permission for everyone. Then with Python script I copy it, fill with data and move to another directory. Because I copy this file with Sheets API, service account(that API use to make actions) becomes owner of the file. And then when anyone try to launch App Script from that file, he can't do that because of "error" already mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

When copying the file(s), edit the Permission(s) attached to the copied files.

To do this, add the new user as an editor(at least).

You can do this using the Spreadsheet Class(as in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addEditor(User)) or the File Class(as in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addEditor(String))

This action would ensure that the new user has the necessary permission to make changes to the file and also run scripts attached to the file, most importantly, all these can be done programmatically

Comment: it doesn't help

Comment: When copying the file, a new file is created. Hence the previous permission no longer exists. You need to manually rewrite the permission to the new(copied) file. This can be done in your Python code. Follow these steps:

(1) Grap the permission object of the file before copying
(2) Proceed to copy the file
(3) Write the permission you got from the previous file unto the copied file(you can add new users as editors or remove an existing user as you please).

The only issue you would have here is when making a cross-domain copy(...@gmail.com account to .a ..@xyz.com account or vice versa)